# GTKmm : Encode image in the file?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I have this UI that displays an image using

```
add(*manage(new Gtk::Image("image.png")));
```

But the app pulls it from the hard drive at each lauch, and if it's not there it's broken, etc. How can I encode image.png so that I can ship it in the code?

Comment: I tried that:
    ```Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pic = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("image.png");
    Gtk::Image* img = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Image(pic));
    add(*img);
```
But it's even worse, if the image is missing at run time, it coredumps ; How can I encode image.png so that I can ship it in the code, so the app dont't have to find/read an image file?

In GIMP I can save an image as "C source code" or "C header file" but not C++... I tried too.

Answer (score 1):

GResource is very useful for this. It lets you list the resource files (such as images) in a *.gresource.xml file. The glib-compile-resources utility then generates a .c file from that, and you link that .c file into your application. You'll need some Makefile.am changes to make that happen properly, but you can look in some existing projects, such as my Glom project:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/tree/Makefile_glom.am?id=f79223fa7ebbb0cfc12c6a47366136de478d57cb#n44

You can then use API such as Gtk::Image::set_from_resource(). Or you can get the data directly with API such as g_resources_open_stream() or even iterate through all the available resources with g_resources_enumerate_children().

Here's some relevant commits from my Glom project:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/commit/?id=f79223fa7ebbb0cfc12c6a47366136de478d57cb

https://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/commit/?id=9cd1b6dab94191abbb9392304e867bddb2bba766

Answer (score 0):

Convert "image.png" to an [XPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap) file; FWIW, the standard XPM format is compilable C code. But more importantly, there are pixbuf and pixmap functions that can directly load XPM data.

Answer (score 0):

For gtkmm in Linux, you can convert all resource files (css, glade, images) to one `glib-compile-resources` file. Then one c file will be created. Hence no need to export resource files separately.

In order to do all that first, you need to create `*.gresource.xml` file.

I needed to convert png image to pixbuf format, for some reason png did not work for me. (you may try with png format also)

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/myproject">
    <file preprocess="xml-stripblanks" alias="tiltdisplay.glade">Resources/tiltdisplay.glade</file>
    <file alias="styles.css">Resources/styles.css</file>
    <!-- png image is converted to pixbuf image using command >
    < gdk-pixbuf-pixdata -r white_argos.png  white_argos.pixbuf-->
    <file alias="white_argos.pixbuf">Resources/white_argos.pixbuf</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

Once this xml file is created you can generate `glib-compile-resources` with the following command.

```
glib-compile-resources --target=path/to/resources.c --generate-source /path/to/my.gresource.xml
```

Once this is done add this `resources.c` to your code. in order to access one item from your c++ code, do the following.

```
img->set_from_resource("/myproject/white_argos.pixbuf"); // gresource prefix + alias
// or
cssProvider->load_from_resource("/myproject/styles.css");
// or
Gtk::Builder::create_from_resource("/myproject/tiltdisplay.glade")
```